# WordPress Iframe IE8 Javascript problem

Tags: browser-compatibility

In a very edge case scenario, I have a site that has an interactive form that uses javascript in an iframe.  It works fine except on a WordPress site using Internet Explorer 8 or less, in which case the javscript does not load.  This iframe also lives on Drupal and vanilla html and php pages, and this error does not happen.

It is a requirement that it work in IE8 and lower.  It's not a wywsiwig editor problem or anything like that, it is something more esoteric happening.  Can anyone help??

This problem can viewed at http://813cash.com and IE8 or lower.

The exactly error message is User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Timestamp: Tue, 21 Aug 2012 19:20:26 UTC

Message: Permission denied
Line: 4
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://lighthousefinance.com/webquote/quote.js

IMPORTANT:  This error does not occur unless the iframe is embedded in a WordPress page.  On a drupal page, no problem, on an html page on the same server, no problem.

I am looking for what possible scenario WordPress might be creating.

Additional WordPress info:
Theme
**Please note:  I have tried embedding this iframe in two completely unrelated WP sites and gotten the same result in IE, so I do not believe it is theme or plugin related**

The site is running a custom theme I built, and iFrame is embeded in two theme templates with the embed code below.  Because the site is live I cannot change to default theme and test, at least not without some risk.

```
<iframe name="cash" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="http://lighthousefinance.com/webquote/quote.php" style="width: 550px; height: 400px;" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0">
```

Active Plugins
Antispam Bee
Backup Buddy
Easy Content Types
Google XML Sitemaps
Redirection
WordPress SEO

Comment: Please add a basic sample code and debug information to your question to make answers possible.

Comment: How are you embedding the IFRAME in the static page? What Theme are you using? What Plugins are active?